# Regex - Credit Card validation

Tags: javascript, regex, credit-card

I'm looking for a way to validate the beginning of a credit card pattern. So for example, let's take MasterCard.

It says that (ref: https://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html):

> MasterCard numbers either start with the numbers 51 through 55...

I'm looking for a regex that returns true when the user enters:

```js
const regex = /^5|5[1-5]/; // this is not working :(

regex.test("5"); // true
regex.test("51"); // true
regex.test("55"); // true
regex.test("50"); // should be false, but return true because it matches the `5` at the beginning :(
```

Comment: Well if it's `51-55` why did you allow `5`? Your second regex pattern's option will **never** be met (it actually will, but anywhere in the credit card number, not at the beginning).

Comment: Just use `^5[1-5]`

Comment: MasterCards start with other BIN numbers, too.

Comment: See @revilheart answer. I was looking for a way to validate the value as the user types in. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you validating as the user types in? If so, you could add an end of line ($) to the first option, so that it returns true only if:

- 5 is the only character typed so far
- The string begins with 50-55

---

```
const regex = /^(5$|5[1-5])/;

regex.test("5"); // true
regex.test("51"); // true
regex.test("55"); // true
regex.test("50"); // false
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do, validate the value as the user types in. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
const regex = /^5[1-5]/;
```

Your regex matches either a string beginning with `5` or a string that has `51` through `55` anywhere in it, because the `^` is only on the left side of the `|`.

If you want to allow a partial entry, you can use:

```
const regex = /^5(?:$|[1-5])/;
```

See [Validating credit card format using regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36537846/validating-credit-card-format-using-regular-expressions) for a regular expression that matches most popular cards.

Comment: Thanks. See the answer above. I was looking for a way to validate the value as the user types in.

Comment: That's going to get very complicated if you want to allow multiple types of credit cards.